# How to add a feature layer on map view using arcgis in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, arcgis, arcgis-server, mkmapview

Can someone guide me to add feature layer with URL on map view using arcgis in iphone application?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a web application as in any of the samples given in the ArcGIS JavaScript API Samples:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/fl_hover.html

Most ArcGis Server stuff works charmingly on mobile devices
The code would look something like this:

```
var southCarolinaCounties = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
              mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
              outFields: ["NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI", "POP07_SQMI"]
            });
southCarolinaCounties.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'");


   map.addLayer(southCarolinaCounties);
```